When I tried to update my anypoint studio version 7.12 to 7.17 I got an error saying: Install Runtime error
error image
 When I tried to update Anypoint Studio from version 7.12 to the version 7.17, the installation abruptly stopped and I got the above error prompt. Is there any solution to this problem?
I have attached the error msg screenshot above
Thank you

With so little information it is not possible to suggest a solution for the error. It could be a network error, some permission issue, some configuration issue or any number of things. Also that there are two years of versions in between may not be helpful.
Instead of trying to upgrade the old version, it is simpler to just download a new installation of the current Anypoint Studio version and install it in a separate directory from the old version. Then you can just open existing workspaces.
